# Grub entry to boot from cd rom?

Tags: linux, grub, boot

What would be the grub entry to boot from cd rom? (so the boot loader of the cd rom should be loaded and executed next)

Grub is installed on the hard disk and should not live on the cd rom. I want to be able to boot an existing cd rom as it is from the grub menu of the harddisk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this](http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanagerdl.html) tool, you copy it to your /boot folder and add an entry in the menu.lst of grub, it will list every possible boot device available including USB even if your mobo does not support it.

Read the instructions and be careful not to mess your boot sector.

Jim

Comment: thank you for pointing me to this very interesting looking plop, i will have a look. seems useful for many things.

Answer (score 1):

First, does grub detect cdrom drives?

If so, I think you need to modify the grub device.map file (/boot/grub/device.map) to add your cdrom device. Then add a chainload section to boot from cdrom, much like the chainload section for Linux-Windows dualbooting. Then install grub again (grub --batch --device-map=/boot/grub/device.map < /etc/grub.conf).

Never tried this before though...